# abstract record

Tags: php, constructor, abstract

I'm trying to create automatic mechanism that will load data from database into object using abstract class that will be extended when neccessary.

Here is my simplified idea, which is not working at the moment, so if someone can explain me why and what i did wrong:

Abstract class:

```
abstract class abstractRecord{

    public $data = array();

    public function __constructor($id = null){
        global $db; // eg. PDO
        $this->db = $db;


        if(!is_null($id) && intval($id) > 0)
            $this->fillData($id);

    }

    public function fillData($id){

        $this->data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table." WHERE ".self::$id."='$id'");

    }

}
```

now some class that will extend abstratRecord and that should on initiation use constructor of abstract to fill data if valid id provided

```
class User extends abstractRecord{

    public static $id = "`id`";
    public static $table = "`users`";

    // some other functions for controlling user...


}
```

and at the very end usage

```
$user = new User(15);  // so user data from db with id=15 should be loaded into object data property by abstractRecord class
```

So this is just simple version, there should be more validation, getters setters interfaces ....

For now just want to know what is wrong in here and why, and is it possible to use this flow without calling parent::__constructor(), as far as I know class should extend abstract __constructor in this case, or maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your abstract class's constructor method is spelled wrong. Needs to be `__construct()`. Then you need to call that constructor in the extended class as follows:

```
class User extends abstractRecord{
    public function __construct() {
        // call to abstractRecore construct
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes that solved some issues, now im having issue accessing properties defined in child class by abstract class, this is very crucial for functionallity, so if i define public static $table = "table_name" i need to be able to use this property in abstract class...

Answer (score 0):

ok i managed to resolve issue and set up working mechanism, so it looks like this:

abstract class abstractRecord{

```
protected $data = array();
public static $table;
public static $pK;

public function __construct($id = null, $table = false, $pK = false){

if($table == false || $pK == false)
    return false;

self::$table = $table;
self::$pK = $pK;

if (!is_null($id) && intval($id) > 0)
        $this->fillData($id);

}

protected function fillData($id){
    global $db; // db solution

    $this->data = $db->("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table." WHERE ".self::$pK."='$id' LIMIT 1");

}

// some other useful functions
```

}

some class

class User extends abstractRecord{

```
public static $table =  " `users` ";
public static $pK = " `userID` ";

public function __construct($id = null){

    parent::__construct($id, self::$table, self::$pK);
}

// some other functions ...
```

}

sorry if something misspelled...

thanks for assistance!